'module' is deprecated warning by Android Studio
I have been using an FTP task defined in build.gradle for a long time. It has been working fine. Android Studio (Iguana) started to warn "'module' is deprecated" for the following recently:
ftpAntTask("org.apache.ant:ant-commons-net:1.10.14") {
    module("commons-net:commons-net:1.4.1") {
        dependencies "oro:oro:2.0.8:jar"
    }
}

I did some search but could not find an alternative for "module". Could anyone offer a tip on this?
